# JavaScript Append Child Value Disappears after appearing for a second

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where I'm creating a dl element with 2 children i.e. one dt and one dd element.

I'm then trying to append the dl element to one of the div in the html file but the data appears for a second and then disappears.

Can someone please point out why the dynamically created elements are disappearing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="test">
   <label for="text_input">Enter Text here</label>
   <br />
   <textarea id="text_input" name="text_input" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="results" class="container"></div>

<script>

const form = document.getElementById("test");

const textArea = document.getElementById("text_input");

const divResults = document.getElementById("results");

form.addEventListener("submit", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("DL");

  var y = document.createElement("DT");
  var txt1 = document.createTextNode("Input");
  y.appendChild(txt1);
  x.appendChild(y);

  var z = document.createElement("DD");
  var txt2 = document.createTextNode(textArea.value);
  x.appendChild(txt2);
  
  document.getElementById("results").appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No such issue.......data appears for a second and then disappears?

Comment: Yeah, as it is it works but I'm using this in express on my end and in my server it is disappearing for some reason.

Comment: Then it is likely a server problem, you should show us what is happening there.

Comment: what's the `z` for? you never used. I think you meant to append textNode to it then append this to container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in order to achieve what you mentioned, you need to append text2 into z instead of directly appending it into x.

```
  var txt2 = document.createTextNode("Black hot drink");
  z.appendChild(txt2);
  x.appendChild(z);
```

Secondly the default behavior of submit button is to POST the form which results in refreshing the page. To avoid this, use preventDefault() method.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var x = document.createElement("DL");

  var y = document.createElement("DT");
  var txt1 = document.createTextNode("Input");
  y.appendChild(txt1);
  x.appendChild(y);

  var z = document.createElement("DD");
  var txt2 = document.createTextNode(textArea.value);
  x.appendChild(txt2);
  
  document.getElementById("results").appendChild(x);
}
```